# Pods affinity to different nodes in StatefulSet

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-statefulset, kubernetes-operator

I am creating StatefulSets and I want pods within one StatefulSet to be distributed across different nodes of the k8s cluster. In my case - one StatefulSet is one database replicaset.

```golang
sts.Spec.Template.Labels["mydb.io/replicaset-uuid"] = replicasetUUID.String()
sts.Spec.Template.Spec.Affinity.PodAntiAffinity = &corev1.PodAntiAffinity{
    RequiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution: []corev1.PodAffinityTerm{
        {
            LabelSelector: &metav1.LabelSelector{
                MatchExpressions: []metav1.LabelSelectorRequirement{
                    {
                        Key:      "mydb.io/replicaset-uuid",
                        Operator: metav1.LabelSelectorOpIn,
                        Values:   []string{replicasetUUID.String()},
                    },
                },
            },
            TopologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname",
        },
    },
}
```

However, with these settings, I get the opposite. `storage-0-0` and `storage-0-1` are on the same replicaset and on the same node...

Moreover, they have exactly the same label `mydb.io/replicaset-uuid`

```
$ kubectl -n mydb get pods -o wide
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP        NODE                           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
storage-0-0                      1/1     Running   0          40m   x.x.x.x   kubernetes-cluster-x-main-0    <none>           <none>
storage-0-1                      1/1     Running   0          39m   x.x.x.x   kubernetes-cluster-x-main-0    <none>           <none>
storage-1-0                      1/1     Running   0          40m   x.x.x.x   kubernetes-cluster-x-slave-0   <none>           <none>
storage-1-1                      1/1     Running   0          40m   x.x.x.x   kubernetes-cluster-x-slave-0   <none>           <none>
mydb-operator-58c9bfbb9b-7djml   1/1     Running   0          46m   x.x.x.x   kubernetes-cluster-x-slave-0   <none>           <none>
```

Comment: Can you describe the resulting StatefulSet in yaml format? `k get statefulset -n mydb storage-0 -oyaml` and check what is the antiaffinity definition?

Comment: @AndD thanks, looked there and found a bug)

Comment: I see. Did you solve the problem then?

Comment: @jesmart, If the problem is solved, please write the solution as an answer.

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak what is written in the description of the problem works correctly
I just indicated the wrong image with the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works correctly, as @jesmart wrote in the comment:

> The description of the problem works correctly I just indicated the wrong image with the application

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using an podAntiAffinity rule in the statefulset definition to deploy your application so that no two instances are located on the same host.

Reference: [An example of a pod that uses pod affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#an-example-of-a-pod-that-uses-pod-affinity)